# Project runs in Chrome but not in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: webdriver, protractor, geckodriver

My project is being executed using chromedriver_2.45, runs perfectly.

the problem starts when I try to execute using geckodriver-v0.23.0, It starts the execution and even makes the login (non angular login) then when it moves to the angular part gives me errors like this:

```
Failed: TypeError: cyclic object value
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'XXXX', ip: 'xxxxx', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '10.0.2'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

also during the execution the webdriver gives me these messages:

```
JavaScript warning: https://www.googletagmanager.com...., line 87: unreachable code after return statement
```

.

```
Angular version is 1.6 
Protractor is the latest version 5.4.2 
Webdriver is version 12.1.1
FireFox 60.3.0esr (32-bit)
```

Any ideas how to make it work? I already tried with older version of gecko and some different configs for the conf.js.. so far nothing worked

*Update*

as requested this is my config file

```
var jasmineReporters = require('./lib/node_modules/jasmine-reporters');
var HTMLReport = require('./lib/node_modules/protractor-html-reporter-2');
var mkdirp = require('./lib/node_modules/mkdirp');
var fs = require('./lib/node_modules/fs-extra');
let date = require('./lib/node_modules/date-and-time');  

var environmentToExecute = 'Dev'

exports.config = {

 seleniumAddress: 'http://'+process.env.AUTOTEST_ADDRESS+'/wd/hub',
 framework: 'jasmine2',

  specs: [ALL MY SPECS],

  suites: {[ALL],[THE],[SUITES] },
  allScriptsTimeout: 20000,
  onPrepare: function () {Jasmine reporter preparation}
  onComplete: function() {Getting xml and converting to html}

  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    isVerbose: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 100000
  },

  multiCapabilities:
  [
   {
     browserName: 'firefox',
   }
 /*{
    Chrome and IE stuff...
   }*/
  ],
};//This is the end of Conf.js
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you try down grading your firefox browser version

Comment: Сould you please provide your protractor conf file?

Comment: Hello, I managed to get the version 56, will try today.
Just added the config file, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was basically the Firefox version and where it was installed.
After downgrading the Version to 57.00 (the last version supported by gecko 23) the tests started and still no success, then I saw that the company configured the Mozilla to always be the same version.
I installed in a different folder and then pointed it in my config file:

```
"browserName": "firefox",
'marionette': true,
"firefox_binary": "C:/Data/Mozilla/firefox.exe",
"binary_": "C:/Data/Mozilla/firefox.exe"
```

Then when protractor starts it opens the version 57 and not the 60 as it was happening before.

Now the Enter key is not working but thats another thing hehehe

Answer (score 0):

Try with below setup

**Config.js**

```
  directConnect: true,
  capabilities : {
    browserName : 'firefox'
  }
}
```

Hope `directConnect: true` helps you to run script successfully.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer, I already found the problem and have it running, but anyway will see this directConnect: true if makes any difference in the execution, thanks!

Comment: Please do mark the answer as correct if directConnect works for you.